# Jenkins windows docker fails to run image, working directory is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have an installation of Jenkins on my windows 10 machine and I'm trying to run the basic node.js pipeline example. When Jenkins tried to run the image I listed in the Jenkinsfile, I get this error:

```
Failed to run image 'node:7-alpine'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:\Users\Joel\.jenkins\workspace\symview-3_master' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.

See 'docker run --help'.
```

This is the Jenkinsfile I am using:

```
pipeline {
     agent {
        docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix the absolute path issue on windows?

Comment: did you found something ?

Comment: I did not. I gave up using Jenkins and started using gitlab ci

Comment: You can not run linux docker host in windows via docker-workflow-plugin ie agent{docker...} syntax, however check  https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/pull/184

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment, Jenkins Docker Pipeline plugin on the Windows host can't execute Linux Docker images due to a bug https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-60473

Comment: At the moment? It's 3 years 4 months later and still the same problem!

Comment: Is there any solution so far ?

Comment: Still the same 1 yr after...

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the working directory path as below (escape each slash with `\`)

```
C:\\Users\\Joel\\.jenkins\\workspace\\symview-3_master
```

Comment: Where do I change that path? In config.xml of the .jenkins folder?

Comment: Is your jenkins running as a docker image? The path you need to edit would probably be workspaceDir.

Comment: No it's not, just installed it directly in windows 10 using the jenkins.war file from the getting started guide. Should I be running it as a docker image?

Comment: No, you don't need to run jenkins as a docker image.

Comment: Have the same problem. Problem is, this path is provided to docker by Jenkins itself, not by ourselves. I don't see a chance to make such replacement.

Comment: You can not run linux docker host in windows via docker-workflow-plugin ie agent{docker...} syntax, however check github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/pull/184

Comment: @JoelB , in my case, the environment variable `JENKINS_HOME` is set in `c:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jenkins.xml`.  It can be verified at "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System".