# Jenkins pipeline docker agent - docker run error - Failed to run image - java.io.IOException

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have tried used jenkins with docker, both are installed on my machine (w10) and I run docker images with jenkins. But when i followed the example in the jenkins documentation ([example from doc](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/getting-started/)) it didn't work. Different pipeline scripts worked when not involving the `agent { docker ... }`, I also tried adding the `docker plugin` from the jenkins config interface.

**pipeline script**

```
// Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline)
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'maven:3.3.3' } }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**error stack**

```
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -d -t -w "C:/Users/A/.jenkins/workspace/first-pipeline_master/" -v "C:/Users/A/.jenkins/workspace/first-pipeline_master/:C:/Users/A/.jenkins/workspace/first-pipeline_master/" -v "C:/Users/A/.jenkins/workspace/first-pipeline_master@tmp/:C:/Users/A/.jenkins/workspace/first-pipeline_master@tmp/" -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** maven:3.3.3 cmd.exe

Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'maven:3.3.3'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/Users/A/.jenkins/workspace/first-pipeline_master/' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'.
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.WindowsDockerClient.run(WindowsDockerClient.java:57)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:199)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:286)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(Docker.groovy:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.node(Docker.groovy:66)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(Docker.groovy:114)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.DockerPipelineScript.runImage(DockerPipelineScript.groovy:54)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.configureRegistry(AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.run(AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:52)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.CheckoutScript.checkoutAndRun(CheckoutScript.groovy:61)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:84)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56136415/jenkins-windows-docker-fails-to-run-image-working-directory-is-invalid-it-need) on SO (the same but no clear solution)

Comment: Try switching to windows containers, restart and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your working directory and `-v` should be like :

```
docker run -d -t -w /$PWD -v /$PWD:/$PWD .......
```

that is because of thw windows path it should be `//`

**UPDATE**

I think there is now no solution for it the [case](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48518) is still open an currecnt

Comment: how do I modify the path? It's auto generated is there a way in config?

Comment: Proper bug link is https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-60473. It's open as well.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue just adding the environment parameter HOME equals to the dot value. I tried with the workspace value also but it didn't worked.
The main idea is to modify the workspace folder path to the right one.

```
pipeline {
        agent { docker { image 'maven:3.3.3' } }
        stages {
            stage('build') {
                environment {
                  HOME="."
                }
                steps {
                    sh 'mvn --version'
                }
           }
        }
    }
```