# Jenkins pipeline issue with Docker - "working directory is invalid"

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am working through the Jenkins Maven/Java app tutorial [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/).

The pipeline fails, saying the working directory is invalid - and that the directory needs to be absolute. Here is the error output:

```
$ docker run -d -t -v /root/.m2:/root/.m2 -w C:/Users/ralph.connors/.jenkins/workspace/simple-java- 
maven-app/ -v C:/Users/ralph.connors/.jenkins/workspace/simple-java-maven- 
app/:C:/Users/ralph.connors/.jenkins/workspace/simple-java-maven-app/ -vC:/Users/ralph.connors/.jenkins/workspace/simple-java-maven-app@tmp/:C:/Users/ralph.connors/.jenkins/workspace/simple-java-maven-app@tmp/ -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** maven:3-alpine cmd.exe
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'maven:3-alpine'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/Users/ralph.connors/.jenkins/workspace/simple-java-maven-app/' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'.
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.WindowsDockerClient.run(WindowsDockerClient.java:57)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:199)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:286)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
...
```

According to posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56136415/jenkins-windows-docker-fails-to-run-image-working-directory-is-invalid-it-need) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447566/jenkins-pipeline-docker-agent-docker-run-error-failed-to-run-image-java-io?noredirect=1&lq=1), the issue is with how Jenkins is using Windows paths in the Docker CLI. However, there were no solutions given.

**Additional info:**

- Jenkins version: 2.201.1
- Docker version: 19.03.5 build 633a0ea
- Windows version: Windows 10 Pro

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn test'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    junit 'target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deliver') {
            steps {
                sh './jenkins/scripts/deliver.sh'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At the moment, Jenkins Docker Pipeline plugin on the Windows host can't execute Linux Docker images due to a bug https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-60473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the windows path notation to work you have to be-

**A.** Running docker desktop (not a generic docker binary)

**B.** Have a shared drive in the docker desktop settings (the drive you're trying to use the path on)

**C.** Be running the commands with the same user that owns the shared drive.

Odds are none of the above are true in your jenkins agent. I would *strongly* suggest pretending that your agents that are running linux containers are running in linux. Use all linux style paths, run the agents in a linux based container (you probably already are), and just use the VM disk directly for filesystem access.

Comment: I am currently running both Jenkins and Docker Desktop on Windows. Are you suggesting that I continue to run Jenkins on Windows, but start a Linux VM on my machine as a Jenkins agent?

Comment: You are already running a linux VM... that's how docker desktop works. Docker doesn't actually work on Windows ;) The integration isn't completely smooth- volume mounts are a pain point. My suggestion would be to use `docker run` to create your jenkins agents inside a linux container so that they handle paths in the way that docker expects and you don't have to think about it.

Comment: I have added my Jenkinsfile to my post. It seems the pipeline is already trying to create a Jenkins agent in a Linux container with a `docker run` using the `maven:3-alpine` image? The `docker run` command is where the pipeline fails.

Comment: With that configuration (using the `docker agent` command in a pipeline), your jenkins master handles setting up the workspace and then issuing the docker run command directly. (I had assumed you were running a standalone agent). The problem is the same though- the docker user can't mount the workspace into a container. I would either A. Run traditional agents inside docker containers or B. set jenkins to have access to the shared disk with the desktop VM. (I am not actually sure how to do that unless you just give it your user credentials)

Comment: The answer looks outdated as current Docker Desktop for Windows uses WSL 2 and there is no shared drive configuration.